# Openfire MAC issue set java_home of android studio app

Tags: java, macos, openfire

I try to start Openfire But it not opening due to JAVA_HOME configuration in **Openfire.sh** file,
I try this [link](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-1615?focusedCommentId=27407&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-27407) it explain as below [image: openfire]

but I try to export java path already pre installed with Android studio in Mac,
I can't able to set below mentioned path in **Openfire.sh**

> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Have you resolved an issue with gradle. ```Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio```

Comment: @VictorShelepen My system already has Android Studio, My question is how to use pre installed Java in AndroidStudio to open fire